# MapKit MKMapView "funny" blue halo crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, mkmapview

Just by curiosity, does anyone ever saw that one?

I don't think (and hope) I will ever reproduce this one... 
So I'm not really looking for a fix, more posting this if someone encounters this one day.

**EDIT** : This is not related to a memory issue releasing the `MKMApView`. the map was displayed, i was scrolling it. (and I only release it on VC deallocation)

I "just" tapped a lil' fast on a `MKMapView` on iOS 4.3.1 during some monkey testing...
I'm in a zone with TONS of wifi networks and not much GPS signal, my guess is that MapView went nuts with all Location events in combination with all the events I triggered. Probably also combined with using `MKReverseGeocoder` at the same time.

FYI, a MKDotBounce is related to user location blue dot... and crash initiated by MKUserLocationAccuracyAnimation... while resuming blue halo...

Btw I already noticed many times that this halo easily get stuck (even on Apple Maps)
Submitted a bugreport with that crash report to Apple...

```
#0  0x35d82698 in ___CFBasicHashFindBucket_Linear ()
#1  0x35cd5654 in CFBasicHashFindBucket ()
#2  0x35cd74a0 in CFDictionaryGetValue ()
#3  0x346b961a in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingCustomization) observationInfo] ()
#4  0x346b95da in _NSKeyValueRetainedObservationInfoForObject ()
#5  0x346b94d8 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] ()
#6  0x356622d2 in CAAnimation_setter ()
#7  0x35662572 in CAAnimation_setter_kCAValueRetainedPointer ()
#8  0x3566258e in -[CAAnimation setDelegate:] ()
#9  0x35420456 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal(Animations) dotBounceAnimation] ()
#10 0x3541e2ea in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal(Animations) actionForLayer:forKey:] ()
#11 0x35421bd2 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal orderInLayer:beginTime:] ()
#12 0x3541ee28 in -[MKDotBounceAnimation runActionForKey:object:arguments:] ()
#13 0x35421c16 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal orderInLayer:beginTime:] ()
#14 0x3541ee28 in -[MKDotBounceAnimation runActionForKey:object:arguments:] ()
#15 0x35421c16 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal orderInLayer:beginTime:] ()
>>> not a joke, really occured 22k times before EXC_BAD_ACCESS!
>>> smells an endless loop until pool exhaust
#22537 0x35421c16 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal orderInLayer:beginTime:] ()
#22538 0x3541ee28 in -[MKDotBounceAnimation runActionForKey:object:arguments:] ()
#22539 0x35421c16 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal orderInLayer:beginTime:] ()
#22540 0x35422134 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal resumeHalo] ()
#22541 0x35422480 in -[MKUserLocationViewInternal updateHalo] ()
#22542 0x3541ec02 in -[MKUserLocationAccuracyAnimation animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#22543 0x3566771c in run_animation_callbacks ()
#22544 0x35656632 in CA::timer_callback ()
#22545 0x35d46a46 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#22546 0x35d48eca in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#22547 0x35d49844 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#22548 0x35cd9ec2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#22549 0x35cd9dca in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22550 0x356f941e in GSEventRunModal ()
#22551 0x356f94ca in GSEventRun ()
#22552 0x35940d68 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#22553 0x3593e806 in UIApplicationMain ()
#22554 0x00003a0a in main
```

Comment: For information, about submitted bug report to Apple, no reply so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 weeks later, I have not reproduced that bug.

Answering to my own question, since obviously no one seen that one...

---

**EDIT** : Many weeks later:

Had an answer from Apple on my bug report, it is supposed to be fixed in iOS5. Not reproduced anyway, and that, on any iOS version. My guess it is a very rare bug in extreme race conditions.

> This is a follow-up to Bug ID# 9234544.
>
> Engineering believes this issue has been addressed in iOS 5.0 beta 1 (9A5220p).
>
> After installing the iOS 5.0 beta 1 software, please update this bug report with your results.

Comment: Vincent, do you have a link to Apple's answer to your bug report?

Comment: @Tuyen added the apple mail content, no more details.

Answer (score 1):

try this before deallocating your MKMapview

```
[self.mapView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

It's a well known bug in MKMapView, if an animation callback comes back to the map view after it's been deallocated, it blows up.  I'd expect Apple to mark your bug report as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks but... This is not related at all to releasing MapView and occured while MapView was displayed and therefore not deallocated. I was scrolling it.